# Необходимо привязать один объект поверх другого Unity C#. Чтобы при движении один из них был статичен

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: пример]

Мне необходимо сделать так чтобы при любом движении объект А был всегда привязан к объекту В.

Comment: Картиночки это конечно хорошо, но вы лучше предоставьте свои попытки решения, даже если они неправильные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю подойдет наследование.

Это можно сделать через редактор Unity, просто перетащите на вкладке Hierarchy объект A на объект B.

Также это можно сделать из кода у объекта A:

```cs
transform.parent = <ОБЪЕКТ GAMEOBJECT>.transform;
```